# data won't refresh in the dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have a trouble with my useState, when i update my data in my useState the data did not change in my rendere

my useState :

```
 const [data,setData] = useState(question.choices.reduce((prev,cur) => {
        prev[cur.uuid] = {
            uuid: cur.uuid,
            checked:false,
            qte:0,
            choicePoint:cur.choicePoints,
            name:cur.name
        }
        return prev
    },{} as Record<string,ICheckBox>));
```

I use this to show my data :

```
 question.choices && question.choices.map(e => (
                    <div key={e.uuid}>
                     <Checkbox key={e.uuid} checked={data[e.uuid].checked} onClick={() => {handleCheckBox(e)}}>{e.name}</Checkbox>
                    </div>
                ))
```

And my function HandleCheckBox :

```
 const handleCheckBox = (choice:IChoice) =>{
        if(data[choice.uuid].checked == true){
            data[choice.uuid].checked = false;
        }else if((data[choice.uuid].checked == false)){
            data[choice.uuid].checked = true;
        }
    }
```

if any one have a idea, this bug is weird i don't understand why my "checked" did not change when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating your state. This is a mutation:

```
data[choice.uuid].checked = false;
```

You shouldn't mutate your state, you should provide a new state and set it with your state setter function. This is why you have a `setData` there.

```
function handleCheckbox(choice) {
  setData((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [choice.uid]: {
      checked: !prev[choice.uid].checked,
    },
  }));
}
```

Comment: I do : `const d = data;
        if(d[choice.uuid].checked == true){
            d[choice.uuid].checked = false;
        }else if((data[choice.uuid].checked == false)){
            d[choice.uuid].checked = true;
        }
        setData(d);` not working too, if i close my component and re open it, my checkbox are checked ....

Comment: `prev` means the previous (or some uses current name) state. We are doing a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) here. You should read all the documentation about hooks API. You don't need this `if/else`, you are just toggling the value. Try to use my example. Also, you are still mutating your state.

Comment: prev and cur are only when i use reduce right ?, your exemple not working actualy ...

Comment: It is not related to `reduce`. You should use it whenever you use the current state. Just go through the documentation. For your issue, a sandbox would be very useful. You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleCheckBox = (choice:IChoice) =>{
        setData((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [choice.uuid]: {
                checked: !prev[choice.uuid].checked,
            }
        } as Record<string,ICheckBox>));
      }
```

Is the correct way, thx devserkan

Comment: You are welcome but you don't need to provide the answer yourself again :) You have already accepted mine and this is the right way.